# $http being invoked without ngclick or ngsubmit event in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am having trouble figuring out why `$http` service from within two of my controllers is fired upon moving to their associated routes. I tried creating additional functions within these controllers and those aren't being fired, so I suspect this has something to do with $http. Doe the `$http` service in a controller always get fired upon instantiation of the controller? My goal is to make sure that the postreq function is fired with directives such as ng-click and ng-submit and not upon instantiation.

Here is my code:

**mainCtrl.js**

```
angular.module('LiveAPP.main', [])
    .controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', mainCtrl]);

function mainCtrl($scope, $http, $location) {
    $scope.funcCheck = function() {
        console.log("this is firing")
    }

    $scope.postreq = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: "/",
        data: {
            user: "Junior",
            password: "Thisispassword"
        }
    }).success(function() {
        console.log("User posted to the database")
    });
}
```

**signUpCtrl.js**

```
angular.module('LiveAPP.signUp', [])
    .controller('signUpCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', signUpCtrl]);

function signUpCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $scope.number = 100;
    $scope.funcCheck = function() {
        console.log("this is firing")
    }
    $scope.postreq = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: "/",
        data: {
            user: "Junior",
            password: "Thisispassword"
        }
    }).success(function() {
        console.log("User posted to the database")
    });
};
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html> 
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js">
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/pure-min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/styles.css">


  </head>
  <body ng-app='LiveAPP'>
    <div ng-view></div>
    <script src="/controllers/mainCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="/controllers/signUpCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="/routes.js"></script> 
  </body>

</html>
```

**routes.js**

```
angular.module('LiveAPP', ['ngRoute','LiveAPP.main','LiveAPP.signUp'])

.config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
$routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl : '/home.html',
    controller  : 'mainCtrl'
  })
  .when('/signup',{
    templateUrl : '/signup.html',
    controller  : 'signUpCtrl'
  })

});
```

Comment: You would need to move ` $http({...` inside specific functions..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a service/factory for any $http request, but in your case, yes you will need to put this in a function because at the moment it is being called immediately.

```
$scope.postreq = function() {
    $http({
        method: "post",
        url: "/",
        data: {
            user: "Junior",
            password: "Thisispassword"
        }
    }).success(function() {
        console.log("User posted to the database")
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. What is the reason you are suggesting using a service or factory for $http requests?

Comment: It all depends on what sort of application you are planning to build I suppose, and if the data will be shared across multiple controllers.  To quote, _"Abstracting the $http call like this will allow you to reuse this code across multiple controllers. This becomes necessary when the code that interacts with this data becomes more complex."_ You can also take advantage of using promises.